# Scala Play not found: value routes

Tags: scala, playframework

I have looked at other answers for this question but the answers are not related to my problem.

Firstly the following works in a html view:

```
<li><a href="@routes.TutorialController.entry">Tutorial</a></li>
```

but the same does not work in my tests and I get the error not found value: routes:

```
 override val relativeUrl = Some(routes.CustomiseController.entry.url.tail)
```

I am testing the page has been loaded in my test by first getting the url to the controller, with reverse routing. I have already tried:

```
sbt clean
sbt clean compile
```

- importing controllers.routes (which works in previous projects).
- Double checking my routes file syntax.

Comment: what version are you on for play/sbt/scala ? which testing lib are you using?

Comment: @AndyHayden `import controllers.routes`

Comment: @Barry                                                                            `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test,
  "com.github.tomakehurst" % "wiremock" % "1.33" % "test"
)`

Comment: What package is `CustomiseController` in?

Comment: @AndyHayden shown in the 3rd comment (1st reply to you)

Comment: @MichaelZajac `package test.acceptance.page` that shouldn't really matter as I am referring to objects/classes outside the package.

Comment: The package _does_ matter when dealing with reverse routes.

Comment: @MichaelZajac yes but I thought it only mattered when refereeing to what you need, not from where you are referring from (in this case). Not the case all the time.

Comment: It's difficult to say for sure without more context.